# Unable to give particular user access to a particular object in GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, cloud, bucket, s3-iam-policy

Need to give access to a particular user to access a particular bucket object in gcp bucket storage.

Help with the IAM policy and what will be the steps for giving this permission.

I have tried with the various IAM policy and custom role policies...

I was expecting someone to help me in that to permit me to a particular user to access a particular bucket object in GCP.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it, one via cli, and another in UI.

1. Cli command using gsutil `gsutil iam ch user:[USER_EMAIL]:[ROLE] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`

   ```
   # Example for Storage Object Viewer
   gsutil iam ch user:example-user@gmail.com:roles/storage.objectViewer gs://your-bucket-name
   ```
2. Grant access to principal (user) in the bucket by going to `bucket > permissions > grant access`
   [image]